# draw Elliptical arc raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am trying to draw an elliptical arc which can animate(bounce) using raphael. So far I have been following http://jsfiddle.net/jonhartmann/vm0etvz9/light/  to draw the arc. This is the output which I am getting from the link above.
[image]

But I need to get an output like an shell(below Image) starting the arc from 2nd quadrant with x=-30 and y=0(x can be anything on negative x axis depends on RADIUS and y should be 0).

[image: Image 1]

I have attached my version of code to achieve the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/vssb7n25/

```js
var archtype = Raphael('graph', 100, 100);


archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (value) {
            var xloc = 50,
            yloc = 50,
            total = 100,
            R = 30,
            alpha = 180 / total * value,
            a = (180 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
            x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            path;
            if (total == value) {
                path = [
                        ["M", xloc, yloc + R],
                        ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
                        ];
            }else{
                path = [
                        ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                        ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
                        ];
            }



return {
            path: path
            };
        };
```

It works fine but adds an extra arc on the bottom.

Could anyone help me out in drawing raphael elliptical arc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the original sample you need to change starting and ending points of the arc.

The starting point (-1,0) becomes

```
["M", xloc - R, yloc],
```

And the ending point is

```
x = xloc - R * Math.sin(a),
y = yloc - R * Math.cos(a),
```

Comment: Hi paiv, it didn't work. I tried but it gives different shapes when going through values from 0-100. I want something like this, When the values is 0- coordinates(-30,0), 50(50,20) and when 100(80,50). The coordinates completely relies on radius.

Comment: Hi Paiv, I apologize, it did work. thank you for your answer